# Compilar y asignar librerias en modo DEBUG en Java de Android

Tags: java, android-studio

Uso las siguientes librerías solo que estén disponibles en `modo debug`

```
debugCompile 'com.github.brianPlummer:tinydancer:0.0.9'
debugCompile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.1'
debugCompile 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:2.0.0'
```

En el `MainActivity.java` lo que quiero que solo se compile si se está en `modo debug`

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
...
}
```

El problema viene cuando pongo a compilar en modo `release` que los `imports` de esas librerías, me da error que no las encuentra.

```
import com.codemonkeylabs.fpslibrary.FrameDataCallback;
import com.codemonkeylabs.fpslibrary.TinyDancer;
import com.facebook.stetho.Stetho;
import com.uphyca.stetho_realm.RealmInspectorModulesProvider;
```

Es obvio porque no las debe cargar, en el gradle está definido solo cargalas si se está en modo debug.

¿Me pregunto si  hay una forma de especificar en el `import ...;` que solo se importe en modo debug?

Comment: Buenos días @Webserveis, una pregunta, si las deshabilitas estas seguro funcionaría tu aplicación en modo "release"?

Comment: @Elenasys, si cuando quiero compilar en release quito los imports, funciona perfectamente, pero me obliga a poner /* */ todo el bloque de if(BuildConfig) ya que los elementos necesitan sus referencias a las librerías.
Digamos lo que necesito si hay una anotacion para decidir si el import .... en que flavor lo usa.

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres solucionarte el tema con las dependencias y los imports, puedes usar un `Interface` conjunto con una fabrica para evitar que tienes que cambiar código.

**Un ejemplo**

Imaginemos que tienes los siguientes paquetes en *main*:

- main/modelo
- main/vistas
- main/controladores
- main/dao
- main/api

De las clases de las dependencias que tienes puedes extraer métodos en un `Interface`. por ejemplos de un Objeto de BBDB necesitas:

```
package api

public interface IBdConexion{

    public Map<String,Object> getQueryResult(Object[]... data);
    public boolean connect(String host, String user, String password);
    // ademas agregemos un método para ver si la conexión es posible. 
    public boolean puedeConectar();
}
```

Ahora tienes la posibilidad de crear dos variantes de una clase que implementa este interfaz:

- debug/dao/MiBdConexion.java
- release/dao/MiBdConexion.java

En debug implementas una clase que tiene todos los imports de las dependencias:

```
package dao

import com.dependencia.uno.*;
import org.dependencia.dos.*;

public class MiBdConexion implements IBdConexion{

    @Override
    public Map<String,Object> getQueryResult(Object[]... data){
         // implementación
    }

    @Override
    public boolean connect(String host, String user, String password){
         // implementación
    }

    @Override
    public boolean puedeConectar(){
         // implementación
    }
}
```

En release otra implementación sin los imports:

```
package dao

public class MiBdConexion implements IBdConexion{

    @Override
    public Map<String,Object> getQueryResult(Object[]... data){
         // implementación
    }

    @Override
    public boolean connect(String host, String user, String password){
         // implementación
    }

    @Override
    public boolean puedeConectar(){
         return false;        }
}
```

Finalmente podemos implementar por ejemplo una manera de obtener la implementación que necesitemos en main/controladores, sin la necesidad de cambiár código en main:

```
public class MiConexionFactory{

    public static IBdConexion getConexion(){
         IBdConexion con = (IBdConexion) Class.forName("dao.MiBdConexion").newInstance();
         return con;    
    }
}
```

El método `getConexion()` va devolver la clase correspondiente al build que implementa la interfaz. Así podemos acceder a todos métodos que necesitemos vía la interfaz sin necesidad de cambiar los imports en el resto del código.

Comment: Muy interesante lo que comentas